# Let $F$ be the reflection through the $y$-axis. Prove that the image under $F$ of a ray is again a ray.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

This is exercise 10d-ii, page 235 of S. Lang's "*Basic Mathematics*".

**My approach:** Given two points $P$, $Q$ such that $P \ne Q$, we can define the ray with vertex $P$ passing through $Q$ to be the set of all points such that
\begin{align}
P + t(Q-P), \text{ for $t\ge$0}
\end{align}

Let $P=(p_{1}, p_{2})$ and $Q=(q_{1}, q_{2})$. Then $$Q-P = (q_{1} - p_{1}, q_{2} - p_{2})$$

The ray with vertex $P$ passing through $Q$ consists of all points
\begin{gather}
&(p_{1}, p_{2}) + t(q_{1} - p_{1}, q_{2} - p_{2}) \\
= & (p_{1} + tq_{1} - tp_{1}, p_{2} + tq_{2} - tp_{2}) && \text{component-wise sum of points} \\
\end{gather}

By definition, under $F$, every point $M=(m_{1}, m_{2})$ of the plane is associated with the point $(-m_{1}, m_{2})$.
Therefore, for all points of the ray with vertex $P$ passing through $Q$ we associate, under $F$, the points
\begin{gather}
& (-[p_{1} + tq_{1} - tp_{1}], p_{2} + tq_{2} - tp_{2}) \\
= & (-p_{1} - tq_{1} - [-tp_{1}], p_{2} + tq_{2} - tp_{2}) && \text{distribute minus sign} \\
= & (-p_{1} + t[-q_{1}-(-p_{1})], p_{2} + t[q_{2} - p_{2}]) && \text{distributivity} \\
= & (-p_{1}, p_{2}) + t(-q_{1}-[-p_{1}], q_{2} - p_{2}) && \text{component-wise sum of points} \\
\end{gather}

Which by definition is the ray with vertex $(-p_{1}, p_{2})$ passing through $(-q_{1}, q_{2})$.
Hence the image of a ray under $F$ is again a ray. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

**Question:** Is this proof correct? Is there a more elegant proof without deviating too much from these definitions? Thank you and sorry about the extra-parenthesis; they make the expressions a bit long but easy to see the answer from the definition in my opinion.

Comment: Your work is correct. Intuitively, this is clear, and you already know that the new ray is the one starting with $(-p_1, p_2)$ and passing through $(-q_1, q_2)$. So, you need to verify this using the definition of a ray and that of a reflection. Essentially, there can't be another way to do it.

Comment: If the author's name is Serge, then probably the name is *Lang*, not *Lange*.

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed the typo on the author's name.